# Is it really useful to feed posts already edited into the review "first posts" queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have been presented with posts in the *first posts* queue which have already been edited by high rep users (who should know what they are doing :-)).

That is no big problem but seeing that this queue is the biggest one anyway it seems a waste of resources.

So I'd like to have the queuing algorithm ignore such posts.

Two recent examples :
[edited by mitch](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/119579), [edited by seth](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/119584)

Comment: Another example: http://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/119756